# Применение css свойств к конкретной странице при печати возможно?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Возможно ли задать css свойства начиная со второй страницы при печати html документа? @page{}

Comment: Более корректно сформулируйте вопрос. Стилизовать можно только глобально, но... если мы используем PHP генератор или какие то другие, то возможно создать любой шаблон и стилизовать не сколько печатных страниц. Также никто не отменял JS. С помощью CSS можно только глобально

Comment: Есть простая html страница (локально, без php). При ее распечатке верхний отступ на второй странице очень мал. При этом на первой все ок. Если задать через css- то ту увеличатся отступы всех страниц. Как можно задать отступы только второй странице при печати.

Comment: Можно задать свойство глобально, и повлиять на первую страницу с помощью @page :first { margin: 1cm }